# Como obter valores de um TextView de uma outra Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria de obter o email que foi digitado na tela de login e com esse valor passar para outra Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Se não mudou desde que eu usei há algum tempo atrás, você pode tentar com Intent e Bundle.

Na classe A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ClasseA.this, ClasseB.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("email", "exemplo@email.com");

i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Na classe B:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");  
}
```

Comment: Ele está sinalizando o seguite erro na ClasseB "'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in 'ep.gismed.gismed.Activity.Home'"

Comment: Veja se colocou o @Override ou se já não havia declarado onCreate.

Comment: O que faço se já estiver declarado o onCreate?

Comment: Você coloca o comando email = getIntent().getExt... no que você já havia declarado. É apenas uma sugestão, você pode colocar onde você achar melhor.